# How to get all changes to a file in Git, with Lib2GitSharp

Tags: c#, .net, git, libgit2sharp

I want to be able to Get a list of all changes done to a file. I've seen this post 
[How to get file's contents on Git using LibGit2Sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034239/how-to-get-files-contents-on-git-using-libgit2sharp), but this requires to start off with a commit. I want to start digging with the filename.

Also is this possible without getting the whole repo locally?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research I think I found an answer.

```
            /*Small test*/
            using (Repository repo = new Repository(strLocalDeliveryPath))
            {
                var fileHistory = repo.Commits.QueryBy(@"Path/To/file.ini").ToList();

                int i = fileHistory.Count();
            }
```

This is in order newest to oldest, and that suits me fine. I would normally only need the latest version of the file content, but nor i have the option of digging through the history of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283873/602585) for a bit more info, but yes, the functionality was added in `libgit2sharp` 0.22.0. Here's an example:

```
var fileHistory = repository.Commits.QueryBy(filePathRelativeToRepository);
foreach (var version in fileHistory)
{
    // Get further details by inspecting version.Commit
}
```